# Expandable menu quick launch SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, office365

Our Company has just moved to Office 365 and I am working on moving our Sharepoint site to the Cloud.

My question is: if I have multilevel libraries, Can I create an expandable menu on Quick Launch that would provide access to all levels of the Library hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer but it might get you started
http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/02/top-navigation-drop-down-menu-quick-launch-flyout.html

I just use completely custom styles for my SharePoint Online sites, the SharePoint master pages are no good to me and the 2013 instance definitely allows more flexibility, hopefully you are running that now.